# OpenMP and #pragma omp atomic

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, atomic

I have an issue with OpenMP. MSVS compilator throws me *"pragma omp atomic has improper form"*.
I don't have any idea why. 
Code: (program appoints PI number using integrals method)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>

long long num_steps = 1000000000;
double step;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    clock_t start, stop;
    double x, pi, sum=0.0;
    int i;
    step = 1./(double)num_steps;
    start = clock();

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (i=0; i<num_steps; i++)
    { 
        x = (i + .5)*step;
        #pragma omp atomic //this part contains error
        sum = sum + 4.0/(1.+ x*x);  
    }

    pi = sum*step;
    stop = clock();

    // some printf to show results
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your program is a perfectly syntactically correct OpenMP code by the current OpenMP standards (e.g. it compiles unmodified with GCC 4.7.1), except that `x` should be declared `private` (which is not a syntactic but rather a semantic error). Unfortunately Microsoft Visual C++ implements a very old OpenMP specification (2.0 from March 2002) which only allows the following statements as acceptable in an `atomic` construct:

> *x* binop= *expr* 
>   *x*++ 
>   ++*x* 
>   *x*-- 
>   --*x*

Later versions included *x* = *x* binop *expr*, but MSVC is forever stuck at OpenMP version 2.0 even in VS2012. Just for comparison, the current OpenMP version is 3.1 and we expect 4.0 to come up in the following months.

In OpenMP 2.0 your statement should read:

```c
#pragma omp atomic
sum += 4.0/(1.+ x*x);
```

But as already noticed, it would be better (and generally faster) to use reduction:

```c
#pragma omp parallel for private(x) reduction(+:sum)
for (i=0; i<num_steps; i++)
{ 
    x = (i + .5)*step;
    sum = sum + 4.0/(1.+ x*x);  
}
```

(you could also write `sum += 4.0/(1.+ x*x);`)

Answer (score 3):

Try to change `sum = sum + 4.0/( 1. + x*x )` to `sum += 4.0/(1.+ x*x)` , But I'm afraid this won't work either. You can try to split the work like this:

```
x = (i + .5)*step;
double xx = 4.0/(1.+ x*x);
#pragma omp atomic //this part contains error
sum += xx;
```

this should work, but I am not sure whether it fits your needs.

Comment: I had to change construction. '#pragma omp reduction(+:sum)' is correct.

Comment: I suggested a solution using atomic..This is the way how it is explained in the official reference site. If the problem is solved good for you.

Comment: @krzakov, `#pragma omp reduction(+:sum)` is not correct. It is likely ignored by the compiler and you get a dangerous data race that is hidden by the numerical imprecision. `reduction` is a clause, it has to be applied to another OpenMP directive - the `parallel for` directive in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Replace :

```
#pragma omp atomic
```

by `#pragma omp reduction(+:sum)`  or  `#pragma omp critical`

But I guess #pragma omp reduction will be a better option as you have sum+=Var;

Do like this:

```
x = (i + .5)*step;
double z = 4.0/(1.+ x*x);
#pragma omp reduction(+:sum)
sum += z;
```

Comment: It helps. More advanced construction than I thought before. I should read a specification.

Comment: `reduction` is a data-sharing clause, applicable to the `parallel` directive (or to the combined `parallel for`), not a directive on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a recap about `#pragma` more than the real solution to your problem.

`#pragma` are a set of **non-standard**, **compiler specific**, and most of the time, **platform/system specific** - meaning that the behaviour can be different on different machines with the same OS or simply on machines with different setups - set of instrunctions for the pre-processor.

As consequence any issue with pragma can be solved only if you look at the official documentation for your compiler for your platform of choice, here are 2 links.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ykxx45t.aspx

For the standard C/C++ `#pragma` doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes. I'm using MSVS, which supports openMP. Btw. I'm using standard MSVS compiler.

Comment: Fortunately, OpenMP pragmas are very well defined in a set of standard documents and any compliant C/C++ compiler should follow exactly the same OpenMP pragma syntax.