# Open MP Atomic directive does not work/mangles variables

Tags: openmp, atomic

I'm all of a sudden having trouble with Open MP atomics and I'm not sure why. I had never bothered to check their output until in a more recent change. I did just change to Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 from 2017.

The problem is that anything under the #pragma omp atomic directive evaluates in a weird way. In one case, I'm trying to increment a variable by += 1.0, but the variable ends up staying at 0.0. Or, I would try to increment a variable by += -0.0012, and the variable ends up as 2.0. Removing the atomic directives seems to work just fine except for race collisions happening of course.

I've tried single threading it and seeing if it was any different. In all cases, the pragma atomic resulted in deterministic but wrong behavior, a += 1.0 results in nothing happening to the variable for example.

Also in all cases single or multithreaded where I remove the pragma atomic, the variables increment correctly.

The atomic is not improperly formed as I don't get that error.

```
struct segment
{
    float transientActivations = 0;
}

#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < chain->curWriteIdx; i++)
{
...

   for (int m = mi; m < mx; m++)
   {
      segment& seg = segments[m];

#pragma omp atomic
      seg.transientActivations += 1.0;
      // if I break here seg.transientActivations is still 0.0
      // however if I remove the atomic, this works fine(except during racing)

   }
...
}
```

No error messages. So there are some questions answered about atomic in MSVC not able to do assignment operator like x = x (binop) a, however I'm always using += which was the solution to that question.

Edit: I did some more tests now and it seems that when I have a single variable that is initialized outside the for loop and shared, then atomic works fine. i.e.:

```
int a = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   #pragma omp atomic
   a += 1; // this works
}
```

Edit2:
After some more testing, the problem is because:
float += 1.0; should be
float += 1.f; 
But I'm not sure why this has to be so strict and why the compiler couldn't fix this. In most cases I was doing my calculations in doubles and then assigning it back to a float without a proper cast. If anyone has insight into this, I will accept a good explanation. Thank you.

Using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 on a windows 10 operating system. I believe this is openMP 2.0 as that's the only version Visual Studio currently supports.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenMP and #pragma omp atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016026/openmp-and-pragma-omp-atomic)

Comment: Hey Mark, yeah I've checked that. I don't get a compiler error. It just doesn't behave well, and my form should be the proper form in that it's += and not just assignment.

Comment: You know what, maybe it's because float += 1.0 (double) does something weird because it's a double incrementing a float. But I'm not sure why it would mess up? Any insight?

Comment: That was it...making it float += 1.f fixes it. I won't answer my own question since I only know how to fix it but not why it is broken. Can someone please help so I can understand why this happened?

Comment: could you post the difference of assembly generated code from code with `1.0` to code with `1.f`?